# Git packfile is truncated

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

When trying to pull using EGit with Eclipse I randomly get the error:

> packfile is truncated

I don't know how and why this occurs. Even importing the project again doesn't help.
What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error and recognized that it always occured when I tried to import in Eclipse while having the local git repository (the directory the repository is going to be copied into) open. **So just closing the file browser and importing again solved my problem.**

Comment: Is this solution applicable to Windows environment?

Answer (score 1):

This problem could possibly be caused by not having enough space to create the pack files, so make sure you are not hitting any space.
For more check at http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/ptp-user/msg02968.html

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing answers work. I had this error with Netbeans.

So I try directly using Git Bash to do my git clone (https address) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, i discovered it was due to the git 'default repository folder' in eclipse, mine was set to a network drive which had a space limit, once I changed to my C drive it worked without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error but finally came to know that its space issue . there was not enough space for in the drive where i checkout the code .So  I changed my drive and checkout the code it went perfectly.