# Packfile is truncated error while cloning Git repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I'm using Egit with Eclipse on Windows to try to clone a repository from private Git. It connects, but while downloading I get the "Packfile is truncated" error. My web browser and file explorer are both closed. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: Packfile is truncated.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CloneOperation.run(CloneOperation.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.executeCloneOperation(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard.access$2(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.AbstractGitCloneWizard$5.run(AbstractGitCloneWizard.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Packfile is truncated.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$SmartHttpFetchConnection.doFetch(TransportHttp.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.fetchObjects(FetchProcess.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1138)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Packfile is truncated.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.fill(PackParser.java:1138)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.access$000(PackParser.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser$InflaterStream.read(PackParser.java:1663)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.whole(PackParser.java:983)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.indexOneObject(PackParser.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ObjectDirectoryPackParser.parse(ObjectDirectoryPackParser.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PackParser.parse(PackParser.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.receivePack(BasePackFetchConnection.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:363)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Have you tried with git at the command line?

Comment: I have not experienced this thing yet, But maybe this post could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897664/git-packfile-is-truncated

Comment: I've read that answer, but as I said, my browser is closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If somebody is getting the same error. The problem was that my internet connection was too slow, and the server has a timeout of 30 seconds.
Tried on a faster internet, worked fine.