# Not able to clone big repositories using JGIT getting packfile truncated error

Tags: java, jgit, cloning

I am trying to clone a big repository from git using JGIT library. The size of file is around 70MB. But am getting Transport Exception: Packfile got truncated. But the same code when i tried to clone a 3MB repo it was working fine. 
My code snippet is below. Since i tried all the possibilites, posting here for some help on what we are missing

1. Git.cloneRepository()
2. Git.open()

   Git git = Git.cloneRepository()
                   .setURI("any repo of size 70MB. since it's company git url am not giving here")
                   .setDirectory(new File(" C drive location "))
                   .setNoCheckout(false)
                   .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("username", "password"))
                   .call();

It should clone the repo in the specified directory with proper .git folder in which heads and origin should be updated with the snapshot of the branch/master we are cloning. But The error stack trace am getting is

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: Packfile is truncated.
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.doFetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$SmartHttpFetchConnection.doFetch(TransportHttp.java:1084)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.BasePackFetchConnection.fetch(BasePackFetchConnection.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.fetchObj`ects(FetchProcess.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:243)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: Try to use [`setTimeout`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.3.1.201302201838-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/TransportCommand.html#setTimeout(int)) to increase the timeout for the transport. Your question seems a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528596/packfile-is-truncated-error-while-cloning-git-repository?rq=1) although that answer is useless...

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta the current execution error am getting after 13 mins. So i felt already its taking more time setting timeout may not be fruitful i feel